# What exactly is the DoJ doctrine on legal cases involving election candidates in close proximity to elections?

Tags: elections, us-president, legal-doctrine

According to a Dutch article from Flemish public broadcasting (https://www.vrt.be/vrtnws/nl/2023/06/14/speedy-trial-of-niet-waarom-ex-president-trump-er-alle-belang/) Trump's attorneys are likely to try and delay his trial as much as possible, until at least November of this year. At that point, it is 90 days until the first Republican primaries, at which point there appear to be rules about avoiding influencing elections.

My question is: What exactly are the established rules regarding this matter? Because if I'm not mistaken, back in 2016 there was a similar incident involving a presidential candidate mishandling documents, which had events happening less than 2 weeks before the elections themselves.